# owl carousel image not applying css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have a carousel of images and i want to have a click event on them so i set them up like this:

```
<div id="comidas" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a class="item opcion" >
        <img class="img" src = "my/path/to/image.jpg" alt = "Image Name" >
    </a >
    <a class="item opcion" >
        <img class="img" src = "my/path/to/image.jpg" alt = "Image Name" >
    </a >
</div>
```

And i got this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#comidas").owlCarousel({
            items : 10
        });

        $('.opcion').on('click', function(event){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
                $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
                $this.children('img').removeClass('selected-option');
            } else{
                $this.addClass('clicked');
                $this.children('img').addClass('selected-option');
            }
        });

    });
```

And here's the css:

```
#comidas .item{
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 3px;
}
#comidas .item:hover{
    background: rgba(242, 130, 13, 0.27);
}

.selected-option {
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

So, what i want is to apply a grayscale filter to the image that's inside the `a` tag, that's because i want to let the user know that it's selected, but it doesn't work!, it adds the class to the `img` element, but it doesn't display any filter.

If someone has a better way of doing so, i'm all ears.

Comment: what browser do you use? did you try  `-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `fliter`'s are browser dependent.. So you can try

```
.selected-option {
     filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
     filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

for different browsers..

**[SOURCE](http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html)**

Comment: Thanks, it works!, how could i apply a filter effect but with a custom color, like orange?

Comment: @JonathanS. Custom colors I am not sure but you can find different options **[here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)** like **sepia**, **invert** etc.,

Comment: Hmmm then i dont want a filter, but how could i make the image look like [this](http://goo.gl/fcgNyp) when clicked?

Comment: @JonathanS. Something like **[this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/image-tint-blend-css/)**? or still you can get various ideas of activating the images from **[here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/css3-image-filters)** and **[demo](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-filters/)**